# DI out from amp to active monitor

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I have an AER Compact 60 amp (guitar and vocal).
Usually the amp itself is enough for me for small places, or churches where it is silent when I perform.
But sometimes it's not enough or the amp is not near me so I can't hear myself well enough.
On the amp I have a DI out, and line out too. So I was thinking to get myself a small active monitor, for example like dB Technologies L160D or dB Technologies Flexsys FM8.

Will that work OK? So, DI out from the amp directly to the active monitor. No mixer, nothing, straight to the monitor.

Do not recommend me a small PA system because I need the kit to be compact, small and portable, easy to travel with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it'll work. Use either - I guess the DI out is a balanced signal using XLR socket, and the line out uses a standard jack socket. If the monitor you get has XLR, it's better to use a two core screened lead to link it to the amp. You may find one is slightly better than the other (line out/DI out), so worth trying both options - with correctly wired leads, of course!

Comment: The XLR output (labeled “DI-Out”) on this amp is line level. So if that output is used, OP should make sure the input device expects line level.

Comment: @trw - I imagine most powered monitors are good for that.

Comment: True enough. :) It's just that people may associate "DI" with mic level. The amp really should label it as another line out.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Yes, I'm aware about Line out (it send volume master , effects...) and DI out (not affected volume master, effects, it just raw signal)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works. I would recommend using the line out.

I sometimes play with my Schertler acoustic amp plugged both into the PA with DI out, and the line out into an active monitor which I have on a stand right next to my ear. Very useful for keeping the sound levels low on stage, without needing in-ear buses.

It is also possible to plug the DI out into the monitor, but this is generally the worse option *for monitoring* because the DI out isn't affected by the amp's master volume knob. (The point of this is that the player can regulate her own amp/monitor level on stage, without affecting what the PA receives.) So, use the DI out if you want that extra speaker for the audience, use the line out if you want it as a monitor.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. Yes, I'm aware about Line out (it send volume master , effects...) and DI out (not affected volume master, effects, it just raw signal)